# Missing Push Notification Entitlement error while there is no push notification implementation

Tags: swift, app-store-connect

I implemented a basic local push notification code to my project, then remove the code and uploaded to itunesconnect. But I receive an email saying that;
"Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app appears to include API used to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the app signature's entitlements do not include the "aps-environment" entitlement..."

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/15011, especially for [the post of morkall](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/15011#48014):

Many others are getting this error too. Obviously it is a false positive.

> morkall
>   Sep 2, 2015 1:34 PM
>   (in response to iCat)
>
> I investigated this issue in MachO View to confirm it's a false-positive.
>
> I could see that in AppDelegate.o - while there are no references to application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: in the symbol table..
>
> ```
> $ nm ./AppDelegate.o | grep application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken  
> $
> ```
>
> I did find the grep output matching, as confirmed in other commenters' reports.
>
> ```
> $ grep application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken ./AppDelegate.o  
> Binary file ./AppDelegate.o matches
> ```
>
> I loaded the binary into MachO View (see screenshot below) and found application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:, application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationWithError: and ALL OF THE OTHER UIApplicationDelegate methods - in the __TEXT segment, __objc_methname section - the list of c string literals that store objc selector names
>
> MachO View Screenshot of __TEXT,__objc_methname section with list of UIApplicationDelegate methods:
>   https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5OWn.jpg
>
> I confirmed this finding with otool here:
>
> ```
> $ otool -v -s __TEXT __objc_methname ./AppDelegate.o  | grep didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken  
> 000000000000bfbb  application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:
> ```
>
> iTunes's review process is strings-based, not nm-based, so their simple grep for didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken will always register a false positive.